# Differentiate f and find the domain of f in interval notation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

$$f(x) = \ln(x^2 − 18x)$$

So first I used the natrual log rules of $\ln(A-B)=\frac{\ln(A)}{\ln(B)}$ and $\ln(x^n)=n\ln(x)$ to rewrite the equation as:

$$f(x)=\frac{2\ln(x)}{\ln(18x)}$$

Then I used the quotient rule, but I think that's where I messed up. Is there an easier way to solve this? And if not, how do you use the quotient rule correctly here? My last question is about solving for the domain. I know the denominator can't be zero, but is there anything else it can't be? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $\ln(A-B )=???!!!$

Comment: The "quotient rule" for the logarithm says that log(A/B)= log(A)- log(B).  It does NOT say that log(A-B)= log(A)/log(B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the interval of definition, you need $\log$ to be defined, which requires
$$
x^2-18x>0\Rightarrow x\in (-\infty,0,)\cup (18,+\infty)
$$
You can just differentiate directly, but do review your log rules. I think those are the source of your difficulties.
$$
f(x)=\ln(x^2-18x)\Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{2x-18}{x^2-18x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

first of all $$\ln { \left( A-B \right) \neq \frac { \ln { A }  }{ \ln { B }  }  } $$ and Domain should be $$\\ x^{ 2 }−18x>0\\ x\left( x-18 \right) >0\\ x\in \left( -\infty ;0 \right) \cup \left( 18;+\infty  \right) $$